# Why can't process this query?(mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem while use mysql. and I completely don't know!.

That problem is...

```
$sql = "insert into Write_Member_Comment(writer, passwd, commentID)
                    values('test', '$passwd' '$commentID')";


mysql_query($sql, $connect);
echo mysql_error();
```

I fill in writer 'test' in temporarily(orginally this is '$writer'), however result is...

```
'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'
```

Here's my Write_Member_Comment table.

```
create table Write_Member_Comment(
writer      char(30) not null,
passwd      char(30) not null,
commentID   int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (commentID) REFERENCES PostComment(commentID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;
```

Why does not working?

Comment: You're missing a comma between the last two values.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma, it should be:

```
$sql = "insert into Write_Member_Comment(writer, passwd, commentID)
                values('test', '$passwd', '$commentID')";
```

Comment: Oh...! I'm so stupid. Sorry and Thanks! I'll have to buy glasses!